# How to check if OkHttp3 request timed out?

Tags: android, timeout, okhttp

I am making an HTTP GET request to a Web Server using the code below:

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

  Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
  for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
  }

  System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

According to [OkHttp document](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/) as shown below, okhttp3 execute calls will throw IOException if the request could not be executed due to cancellation, a connectivity problem or timeout.

> Throws:
>   IOException - if the request could not be executed due to cancellation, a connectivity problem or timeout. Because networks can fail during an exchange, it is possible that the remote server accepted the request before the failure.

I would like to know if there's a way to know if IOException was due to the request getting timed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I could not find any information about timeout exception in okHttp3 documentation, looking at tests [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/b5285cf91f89d186f27285764e6109e0c1c27210/okhttp-tests/src/test/java/okhttp3/CallTest.java#L877) shows that a [SocketTimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) exception will be raised in case of timeouts.

So, to answer my own question, we can catch [SocketTimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) first in order to know if IOException was due to the request getting timed out like below:

```
try {
  // make http request
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // request timed out
} catch (IOException e) {
    // some other error
}
```